Horror/fantasy movie that takes place underground; when the monsters catch a human, the human becomes a monster
This was an 80s movie, I believe. And as a kid, I remember it well, but I only know vivid portions. It's a fantasy kind of film, but horror. I believe it takes place underground, and humans are trying to escape from big, strong monsters that, when they catch a human, the human becomes a monster. I wish I knew more about it, but I've been trying to find this movie for a long time. It's kind of like troll, but not.

Hmmm. I can think of a few cave sf/horror films: WHAT WAITS BELOW (1984), THE CAVE (2005 - but the humans do become monsters), NECRONOMICON (1993 - the last segment is set in a cave with monsters turning people) and, staying Lovecraftian, there are cave monsters in BLEEDERS (1997)

what did the monsters look like? two legs two arms? what color were the monsters? what size were the monsters? 6ft? shorter? taller? did the monsters wear clothes?
